# SQL Server 2008 Batch Insert

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, fluent-nhibernate, bulkinsert

I have a dictionary of about 50,000 words; each word has-many synonyms, antonyms, etc. I'm using Fluent NHibernate and I've created a 10gb MS SQL Server instance for the app and I am trying to populate it as a batch update:

```
public class Word
{
     public virtual int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual string Text { get; set; }
     public virtual IList<Word> Synonyms { get; set; }
     public virtual IList<Word> Antonyms { get; set; }
}

public class WordMapping : ClassMap<Word>
{
    public WordMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).UnsavedValue(0);
        Map(x => x.Text);

        HasMany(x => x.Synonyms).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
        HasMany(x => x.Antonyms).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}
...

List<Word> words = loadWordsFromFile();

using (IStatelessSession session = session.SessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            foreach (var word in words)
                   session.Insert(word);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
```

I've set the batch size to 1000:

```
 private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
 {
    return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration
                         .MsSql2008
                         .ConnectionString(connStr)
                         .AdoNetBatchSize(1000))
                .Mappings(M => M.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<WordMapping>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(Cfg => _configuration = Cfg)
                .BuildSessionFactory();
 }
```

It has been running for hours with no end in sight. Is this the best way to populate my database or is there a more expedient approach when dealing with large datasets?

Comment: Something is wrong if it's been running for hours; I routinely insert this amount of data in much less time. Are you sure that the slow part is the insertion? Or perhaps it's reading from the file?

Comment: Well with the HasMany relationships it is probably around a million rows.

Comment: It's worth noting that I run it just fine locally on SQLite (in memory). Using that configuration, it takes a couple minutes to load everything. I think there must be a lot of round-trips to the MSSQL server, but I have no way of knowing. I've never used T-SQL... is there maybe some way I could just write out all of the queries, connect to the db server, and execute them really fast that way? I'm using AppHarbor, which doesn't allow for local data storage, otherwise I'd just transfer the datafile and populate it that way.

Comment: That still doesn't narrow down the problem. My guess would be with that much data, you're experiencing really high memory usage which is interfering with SQL Server performance. You really need to figure out where it's actually spending time.

Comment: I'm confused. My code loads all the Word objects from a 9mb file into memory, taking about 100mb of the available 4gb of RAM. The only portion taking hours is looping through the words and inserting/committing them to the database. How can I narrow down the performance issues more?

Comment: Could it be so that it tries to do it all in one insert, if so then it will keep a copy of every change in memory for roll back. We experienced something similar using Linq2SQL in c# before finding how to flush the inserts to the database.

Comment: ORMs such as NHibernate are horrible when it comes to performance. I guess they are ok for a handful of users, but if you are dealing with lots of users or lots of data you really need to use a mixture of SqlCommand and SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: For wide rows I generally use a batch size of 10,000. For narrow rows with only a few columns I could see increasing the batch size to 50,000 or more. Even on modest hardware that should still only take under a minute using SqlBulkCopy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like lFoust i also use the SQLBulkCopy utility for quite large ELT into some databases.

Below is a Code Example of the SqlBulkCopy i wrote:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("ConnectionStringHere");
SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlCon);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Rows.Add(// add data to the datatable)

using (sqlBulkCopy)
{

.DestinationTableName = "Putnameoftablehere";
.NotifyAfter = dt.Rows.Count/100; //Notify every 1%
.WriteToServer(dt);
.Close();


}
```

Comment: that code doesn't seem to make much sense starting with the using clause

Comment: Sorry Wesley, i made change to the Using statement to be sqlBulkCopy instead of sBulkCopy. I am sure you can work out the other parts if you need to use it. MSDN has alot of information around SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: BulkCopy is INSANELY fast. For best performance, make sure the order of your columns in your datatable matches the order in the table.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit outside of the NHibernate data access layer you are using but when we load large amounts of data into a database on my team (we have several 20+ TB databases) we use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx). It isn't the most exciting technology wise (using DataTables etc) but it works really well and fast.